# Spring Data JPA @OneToMany JSON response with parent does not return the parent for second instance

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I have two entities in spring data JPA defined as USER AND USER_ACTIVITY with relationship as: each user has many activities.

on my User Entity I defined as

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="user")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id")
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="user_id")
   private long id;

   @JsonIgnore
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
   private List<UserActivity> userActivities;
}
```

and my child entity user activity is defined as

```
  @Entity
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Table(name="user_activity")
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id")
  public class UserActivity {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name="id")
     private long id;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
     private User user;
   }
```

My Repository on activity is defined as

```
  @Repository
  public interface UserActivityRepository extends JpaRepository<UserActivity, Long> {
      public List<UserActivity> findByActivityDateAndTypeAndUserId(Date dt, String type, 
                   long id);
   }
```

when I am using the method findByActivityDateAndTypeAndUserId on the repo, I am noticing that the JSON response for the second instance of does not return the parent. However first activity as the user info. Somehow the response is truncating the parent object in the second record of the array. Here is the same response.

```
0: {
    id: 31
    activityDate: "2020-01-29"
    start: "2020-01-29T20:34:54.000-0500"
    end: "2020-01-29T20:34:54.000-0500"
    type: "CHECK_IN"
    notes: "CHECK_IN"
    user: {id: 92, username: "xyz@gmail.com", firstName: "x", y: "m",…}
1: {
    id: 32
    activityDate: "2020-01-29"
    start: "2020-01-29T20:34:55.000-0500"
    end: "2020-01-29T20:34:55.000-0500"
    type: "CHECK_OUT"
    notes: "CHECK_OUT"
    user: 2
    }
```

See the second item in the array for user field, that's where the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated in this. THank you!

Comment: That is hard to say if you don't show us how you create the user and the activities, or the content of the database you retrieve them from.

Comment: I have created a separate pojo and performed mapping in the service layer and returned this new pojo as response.